# Merging replaces existing values in database with null though using nvl()

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, null

Below stored procedure works fine but Merging replaces existing values in database with null though using nvl()

```
  create or replace PROCEDURE P_UPSERT_CONNECTDISCONNECT
(
  I_SAP_UUID IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
, I_METER_ID IN VARCHAR2 
, I_STATUS IN VARCHAR2 
, I_CUR_SYSTEM IN VARCHAR2 
, I_REQ_CREATION_TIME IN DATE DEFAULT NULL
, I_CAT_CODE IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
, I_PLANNED_TIME IN DATE DEFAULT NULL
, I_ASB_REC_TIME IN DATE DEFAULT NULL
, I_MDM_REC_TIME IN DATE DEFAULT NULL
, I_LOAD_ACT_CODE IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
, I_NRT_REC_TIME IN DATE DEFAULT NULL
, I_NRT_VER_REC_TIME IN DATE DEFAULT NULL
, I_CONF_UUID IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
, I_ERROR_DETAIL IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
) AS 
BEGIN
  MERGE INTO CONNECTDISCONNECT e
     using (select I_SAP_UUID SAP_UUID, I_METER_ID METER_ID,I_STATUS STATUS, I_CUR_SYSTEM CUR_SYSTEM, I_REQ_CREATION_TIME REQ_CREATION_TIME, I_CAT_CODE CAT_CODE, I_PLANNED_TIME PLANNED_TIME,I_ASB_REC_TIME ASB_REC_TIME,I_MDM_REC_TIME MDM_REC_TIME,I_LOAD_ACT_CODE LOAD_ACT_CODE,I_NRT_REC_TIME NRT_REC_TIME,I_NRT_VER_REC_TIME NRT_VER_REC_TIME,I_CONF_UUID CONF_UUID,I_ERROR_DETAIL ERROR_DETAIL   from dual) s
  on (e.METER_ID = s.METER_ID) 
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE SET SAP_UUID      = nvl(I_SAP_UUID, s.SAP_UUID),
                   STATUS            = nvl(I_STATUS, s.STATUS),
                   CUR_SYSTEM        = nvl(I_CUR_SYSTEM, s.CUR_SYSTEM),
                   REQ_CREATION_TIME = nvl(I_REQ_CREATION_TIME, s.REQ_CREATION_TIME),
                   CAT_CODE          = nvl(I_CAT_CODE, s.CAT_CODE),
                   PLANNED_TIME      = nvl(I_PLANNED_TIME, s.PLANNED_TIME),
                   ASB_REC_TIME      = nvl(I_ASB_REC_TIME, s.ASB_REC_TIME),
                   MDM_REC_TIME      = nvl(I_MDM_REC_TIME, s.MDM_REC_TIME),
                   LOAD_ACT_CODE     = nvl(I_LOAD_ACT_CODE, s.LOAD_ACT_CODE),
                   NRT_REC_TIME      = nvl(I_NRT_REC_TIME, s.NRT_REC_TIME),
                   NRT_VER_REC_TIME  = nvl(I_NRT_VER_REC_TIME, s.NRT_VER_REC_TIME),
                   CONF_UUID         = nvl(I_CONF_UUID, s.CONF_UUID),
                   ERROR_DETAIL      = nvl(I_ERROR_DETAIL, s.ERROR_DETAIL)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT (e.SAP_UUID, e.METER_ID, e.STATUS, e.CUR_SYSTEM,e.REQ_CREATION_TIME,e.CAT_CODE,e.PLANNED_TIME,e.ASB_REC_TIME,e.MDM_REC_TIME,e.LOAD_ACT_CODE,e.NRT_REC_TIME,e.NRT_VER_REC_TIME,e.CONF_UUID,e.ERROR_DETAIL)
      VALUES (s.SAP_UUID, s.METER_ID, s.STATUS, s.CUR_SYSTEM,s.REQ_CREATION_TIME,s.CAT_CODE,s.PLANNED_TIME,s.ASB_REC_TIME,s.MDM_REC_TIME,s.LOAD_ACT_CODE,s.NRT_REC_TIME,s.NRT_VER_REC_TIME,s.CONF_UUID,s.ERROR_DETAIL);
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are optional, then declare them as

```
create or replace PROCEDURE P_UPSERT_CONNECTDISCONNECT
(
  I_SAP_UUID IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
, I_METER_ID IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
```

while - within the procedure - you have to decide what to do in cases when they don't have any value.

Your code can be simplified from

```
UPDATE SET 
SAP_UUID = Case When (I_SAP_UUID is not null and I_SAP_UUID <> '') Then I_SAP_UUID Else e.SAP_UUID End,
```

to

```
update set
s.sap_uuid = nvl(i_sap_uuid, e.sap_uuid),
```

---

Also, as in Oracle null is equal to an empty string, you don't have to check that twice, e.g.

```
I_SAP_UUID is not null and I_SAP_UUID <> ''
```

That's just

```
I_SAP_UUID is not null
```

Comment: nvl(I_REQ_CREATION_TIME, s.REQ_CREATION_TIME) , REQ_CREATION_TIME has a date value, but it is getting updated to NULL .. any clues??

Comment: should I do anything for date field for the NVL to work

Comment: No, there's nothing special with DATE datatype as far as NVL is concerned. If possible, create a SMALL example (only relevant columns/parameters) by editing the original question you posted so that we could try to reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: I am passing null value to storedprocedure input but it is replacing the existing  values with NULL. Am I missing something??

Comment: You might not be able to replcate the issue as I am invoking the procedure from a eclipse based tool.

Comment: It shouldn't be acting like what you described; that's just not the way NVL works.

Comment: My requirment is simple , i will passing some values to stored procedure, if the input is not null update it, if the input is null don't update the column. updated stored procedure is updating if the values is passed, if the value is not passed it is updating to null but it shouldn't be. Can you double check the stored procedure once, I am not a DB exper in any way.

Comment: Ah, yes - there's a mistake. You shouldn't use `s.` alias, but `e.` in all NVLs, e.g. `nvl(I_SAP_UUID, e.SAP_UUID)` because `s.` represents input parameter so - if it is NULL, MERGE will update column to NULL.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. @Littlefoot that was the issue :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use DEFAULT to specify default value which will be assigned if parameter is not provided:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE P_UPSERT_CONNECTDISCONNECT
(
  I_SAP_UUID IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
, I_METER_ID IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
, I_STATUS IN VARCHAR2   DEFAULT NULL
, I_CUR_SYSTEM IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
....
```

Another way is to create overloaded procedures (procedures with the same name and different parameters):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE P_UPSERT_CONNECTDISCONNECT(I_SAP_UUID IN VARCHAR2, I_METER_ID IN VARCHAR2) AS
BEGIN
  -- 2 arguments 
END P_UPSERT_CONNECTDISCONNECT;

CREATE PROCEDURE P_UPSERT_CONNECTDISCONNECT(I_SAP_UUID IN VARCHAR2, I_METER_ID IN VARCHAR2, I_STATUS IN VARCHAR2) AS
BEGIN
  -- 3 arguments 
END P_UPSERT_CONNECTDISCONNECT;
```